# Can this be written as a python reduce function?

Tags: python

Can you make this more pythonic by using the map and/or reduce functions? it just sums the products of every consecutive pair of numbers.

```
topo = (14,10,6,7,23,6)
result = 0
for i in range(len(topo)-1):
    result += topo[i]*topo[i+1]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the nicest way I can think of:

```
import operator
sum(map(operator.mul, topo[:-1], topo[1:]))
```

**Edit**: I've just found out there's a better way to do this:

```
import operator
import itertools

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return a, b

def sum_products(l):
    return sum(itertools.imap(operator.mul, *pairwise(l)))
```

Credit for pairwise function goes to the itertools documentation.

This is faster and uses less memory. Of course, it's less concise.

Comment: Just use `topo` instead of `topo[:-1]`

Comment: @Kable, not the same thing... topo[-1] drops the last element.

Comment: While `topo` won't work instead of `topo[:-1]` on Python 2 for `map`, it will work fine with `imap` from `itertools`, and I believe it will also work fine on Python 3.

Comment: agf, while you can do that, it's not really the clearest or shortest way.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `map` and `reduce` like this, but I'm not convinced it's more pythonic:

```
reduce( lambda x, y: x + y, map( lambda x, y: x * y, topo[:-1], topo[1:]) )
```

Probably simpler is this sum + generator expression:

```
sum(topo[x] * topo[x+1] for x in xrange(len(topo)-1))
```

Comment: Thanks, I like your second one.

Comment: Another way to use `sum` would be `sum(a * b for a, b in zip(topo[:-1], topo[1:]))`

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
mult = lambda (x, y): x * y
pairs = zip(list(topo), list(topo)[1:])
result = sum(map(mult, pairs))
```

but is probably harder to understand.

Comment: Instead of defining `mult`, just `from operator import mul`

Comment: I think that actually doesn't work because my lambda takes a tuple…

Comment: @Ben: Just use `map` with multiple iterables: `sum(map(mul, topo[:-1], topo[1:]))`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of map using a list comprehension should work:

```
>>> topo = (14,10,6,7,23,6)
>>> sum((x*y for x,y in zip(topo[:-1],topo[1:])))
541
>>>
```

or

```
>>> sum((topo[i]*topo[i+1] for i in range(len(topo)-1)))
541
```

Comment: Charles Bailey's answer has my solution included and beat me to it by a while. Somehow I missed it in my first glance through the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call this pythonic, though it looks cooler, `reduce` doesn't fit in here:

```
def func(first, *rest):
    return reduce(lambda (x,y),z:(x+y*z,z), rest, (0,first))[0]
```

Note the usage of `(x,y),z` is 2.x only.

Answer (score 0):

With reduce and Python < 3.x:

```
from itertools import tee, izip

#recipe from http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

reduce(lambda s, (x, y):s + x * y, pairwise(topo), 0)
```

with map:

```
from operator import mul
from itertools import tee

a, b = tee(topo)
next(b, None)

sum(map(mul, a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

this can also get your answer

```
a= [14,10,6,7,23,6]
reduce(lambda a,b: a+b,  map(lambda (x,y): x*y, map(lambda i:(a[i],a[i+1]), range(len(a)-1))  ) )
```